# How to display one digit after having decimal point along with their units for numbers using angualrjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, precision

I have following code:

**Controller:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="value in values ">{{value | number:1}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl( $scope ) {
    $scope.values = [ '1', '8.634', '5.25', '(18.26%)', '(56.23pp)', '(10.28)' ];
}
```

If I run the above code, I am getting output like below:

```
1.0
8.6
5.3
```

but I want output like below:

```
1.0
8.6
5.2
18.2%
56.2pp
10.2
```

i.e I want to get the value(s) up to one digit(precision) after decimal point along with their units as well like `%, pp`, etc. Please let me know to do this either using `angularjs`. Thanks.

Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiran88/b3asjf0m/6/).

Comment: Do you need your `$scope.values` to be in this particular format? (With the parentheses)

Comment: @Stratubas, yes, i will get numbers like that format.

Comment: So, to get it right, some numbers will be inside parentheses and some will not have any, and some numbers will have non-numerical strings next to them?

Comment: @Stratubas, yes, exactly. I will get the numbers like that as per my requirements(like some are numbers, some are in paranthesis, some are non-numerical, etc). So, I need to show them as my desired output, I am not sure how can I achieve that ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it can be done better using regex, but that seems to work ok.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);

function getNumberAndPostfix(inputString) {
    let number = '';
    let postfix = '';
    const characters = inputString.split('');
    for (const character of characters) {
        if ('()'.includes(character)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ('0123456789.'.includes(character)) {
            number += character;
            continue;
        }
        postfix += character;
    }
    return { number, postfix };
}

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    const inputValues = ['1', '8.634', '5.25', '(18.26%)', '(56.23pp)', '(10.28)'];
    $scope.values = inputValues.map(string => getNumberAndPostfix(string));
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="value in values">{{value.number | number:1}}{{value.postfix}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much for your help, it is fine ! :-)

Comment: @georgeawg oh, I was missing that controller, that's why I couldn't get a snippet to work :) thx for the edit